# Using Count and Max together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
ID ReceptionDate ResultFixedDateTime FinalMeasurementEndDateTime
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  2014-01-01    2014-01-01 10:20:35 2014-01-01 09:20:35
2  2014-01-01    2014-01-01 10:30:35 2014-01-01 09:40:35
3  2014-01-01    2014-01-01 10:50:35 2014-01-01 09:45:35
4  2014-01-02    2014-01-02 10:50:35 2014-01-02 09:45:35
5  2014-01-02    2014-01-02 10:50:35 2014-01-02 09:45:35
```

I need a result like below that groups by the `ReceptionDate`, total count of the records with the same `ReceptionDate` and the maximum time difference (`ResultFixedDateTime - FinalMeasurementEndDateTime`) for the given `ReceptionDate`

```
ReceptionDate Count      OperatingDiff
--------------------------------------
2014-01-01    3          65
2014-01-02    2          65
```

This query is returning more number of records than expected :

```
SELECT  
    ET.ReceptionDate,
    COUNT(ET.ReceptionDate),
    MAX(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ET.ResultFixedDateTime, ET.FinalMeasurementEndDateTime)) AS OverTimeDiff
FROM 
    ExaminationTimes ET
WHERE 
    ET.ReceptionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate        
GROUP BY 
    ET.ReceptionDate, ET.ResultFixedDateTime, ET.FinalMeasurementEndDateTime
ORDER BY 
    ET.ReceptionDate
```

It's returning the right number of records when I take out

```
MAX(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ET.ResultFixedDateTime, ET.FinalMeasurementEndDateTime)) AS OverTimeDiff
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: the `MAX()` will not affect the number of records return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't group by ResultFixedDateTime & Final MeasurementEndDateTime

```
SELECT  ET.ReceptionDate, 
        COUNT(ET.ReceptionDate),
        MAX(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ET.ResultFixedDateTime, ET.FinalMeasurementEndDateTime)) AS OverTimeDiff
        FROM ExaminationTimes ET
        WHERE ET.ReceptionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate      
        GROUP BY ET.ReceptionDate
        --,ET.ResultFixedDateTime
        --,ET.FinalMeasurementEndDateTime
        ORDER BY ET.ReceptionDate
```